# SyncFusion to SQL connection and showing on the Dashboard

Tags: syncfusion

I just wanted to know whether there is a possibility to connect to the SQL table using SyncFusion, and display the table in the form of a pivot in the Front end. I am using TypeScript for coding. I can also use C# if I need to use. If yes let me know how can I create connection between the SyncFusion and the SQL Table.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Raja

Answer (score 0):

The connection to SQL using SyncFusion can be achieved by using the below code snippet.

```
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //In below provide full path of your database(*.sdf) location.
            string conStringforDB = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Northwind.sdf").Split(new string[] { "\\wcf" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] + "\\Northwind.sdf";
            SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStringforDB);

                con.Open();
                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Top(100) [Order ID], [Product ID], [Unit Price], Quantity
                                                      FROM [Order Details] ", con);
                SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);


                da.Fill(ds);

                //Creation of DataView
                DataView dataView = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
```